# Why does the Mono.Cecil HelloWorld example fail with an exception?

Tags: f#, mono.cecil

```
open System
open Mono.Cecil
open Mono.Cecil.Cil

let myHelloWorldApp = 
    AssemblyDefinition.CreateAssembly(
        new AssemblyNameDefinition("HelloWorld", new Version(1, 0, 0, 0)), "HelloWorld", ModuleKind.Console)

let module_ = myHelloWorldApp.MainModule

// create the program type and add it to the module
let programType = 
    new TypeDefinition("HelloWorld", "Program",
        Mono.Cecil.TypeAttributes.Class ||| Mono.Cecil.TypeAttributes.Public, module_.TypeSystem.Object)

module_.Types.Add(programType)

// add an empty constructor
let ctor = 
    new MethodDefinition(".ctor", Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Public ||| Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.HideBySig
        ||| Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.SpecialName ||| Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName, module_.TypeSystem.Void)

// create the constructor's method body
let il = ctor.Body.GetILProcessor()

il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0))

// call the base constructor
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Call, module_.ImportReference(typeof<obj>.GetConstructor([||]))))

il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Nop))
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Ret))

programType.Methods.Add(ctor)

// define the 'Main' method and add it to 'Program'
let mainMethod = 
    new MethodDefinition("Main",
        Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Public ||| Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Static, module_.TypeSystem.Void)

programType.Methods.Add(mainMethod)

// add the 'args' parameter
let argsParameter = 
    new ParameterDefinition("args",
        Mono.Cecil.ParameterAttributes.None, module_.ImportReference(typeof<string[]>))

mainMethod.Parameters.Add(argsParameter);

// create the method body
il = mainMethod.Body.GetILProcessor()

il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Nop))
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello World"))

let writeLineMethod = 
    il.Create(OpCodes.Call,
        module_.ImportReference(typeof<Console>.GetMethod("WriteLine", [|typeof<string>|])))

// call the method
il.Append(writeLineMethod)

il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Nop))
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Ret))

// set the entry point and save the module
myHelloWorldApp.EntryPoint <- mainMethod
```

I've borrowed [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366963/how-to-use-mono-cecil-to-create-helloworld-exe) from the answer to that question and rewritten it in F#. When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'HelloWorld.Program' from assembly 'Hello
on=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method 'Main' has no implementation (no RVA).
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is caused by the following line:

```
// create the method body
il = mainMethod.Body.GetILProcessor()
```

In C#, this would assign the IL processor for the `Main` method to the `il` variable, but in F#, this is just an equality test which results in `false` - and so the IL code that you wanted to generate for the `Main` method is added to the previous `il` processor for the constructor.

You should be able to fix this using variable shadowing:

```
// create the method body
let il = mainMethod.Body.GetILProcessor()
```

Comment: Yeah, this was it. Though rather than use a let statement it would be better to bind it to a lambda otherwise the duplicate variable error will occur. Also, I've already noticed once before that for some reason F# is not giving me the usual is not unit warning on the equality test, but it did not occur to me to check for the same error again. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic You do not get the equality test warning at the top-level in a script (where you might want to write a number of expressions and run them one by one). You would get those if your code was inside a function (which is a better structure anyway)