# Run Mono.Cecil in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, mono, code-generation, mono.cecil

I ran the HelloWorld console app example from [a SO anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39369989/7821462) compiled with .NET Core 2 and Mono.Cecil 0.10.0-beta7:

```
var myHelloWorldApp = AssemblyDefinition.CreateAssembly(
    new AssemblyNameDefinition("HelloWorld", new Version(1, 0, 0, 0)), "HelloWorld", ModuleKind.Console);

var module = myHelloWorldApp.MainModule;

// create the program type and add it to the module
var programType = new TypeDefinition("HelloWorld", "Program",
    Mono.Cecil.TypeAttributes.Class | Mono.Cecil.TypeAttributes.Public, module.TypeSystem.Object);

module.Types.Add(programType);

// add an empty constructor
var ctor = new MethodDefinition(".ctor", Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Public | Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.HideBySig
    | Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.SpecialName | Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName, module.TypeSystem.Void);

// create the constructor's method body
var il = ctor.Body.GetILProcessor();

il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0));

// call the base constructor
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Call, module.Import(typeof(object).GetConstructor(Array.Empty<Type>()))));

il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Nop));
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Ret));

programType.Methods.Add(ctor);

// define the 'Main' method and add it to 'Program'
var mainMethod = new MethodDefinition("Main",
    Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Public | Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Static, module.TypeSystem.Void);

programType.Methods.Add(mainMethod);

// add the 'args' parameter
var argsParameter = new ParameterDefinition("args",
    Mono.Cecil.ParameterAttributes.None, module.Import(typeof(string[])));

mainMethod.Parameters.Add(argsParameter);

// create the method body
il = mainMethod.Body.GetILProcessor();

il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Nop));
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello World"));

var writeLineMethod = il.Create(OpCodes.Call,
    module.Import(typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { typeof(string) })));

// call the method
il.Append(writeLineMethod);

il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Nop));
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Ret));

// set the entry point and save the module
myHelloWorldApp.EntryPoint = mainMethod;
myHelloWorldApp.Write("HelloWorld.exe");
```

The above code executes fine when compiling with .NET Framework, but when compiling with .NET Core resulted in the error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Console, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> at HelloWorld.Program.Main(String[] args)

I'd like to ask, why can't the HelloWorld app locate the assembly file mscorlib.dll? What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by creating a `HelloWorld.runtimeconfig.json` at the same folder of `HelloWorld.exe` and then ran `dotnet ./HelloWorld.exe`. It would print `Hello World` to the console.

The Json file:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp2.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "2.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must be performing the assembly manipulation from within .net classic, ie .net 4.x. so this means when u do `typeof(Console)` is imports the `Console` from the full runtime, no from the NET Core runtime

Comment: I created a console project and compile it with .Net Core 2.0, would you explain how it could load the .net frameworks assemblies? How can I make sure it would import the correct .NET core runtime?

Comment: Hi Simon, I see that you're also a Cecil contributor. May I ask could I create a new .NET Core assembly file without creating an associating file `.runtimeconfig.json`? I'm looking for creating self-contained assemblies so the runtime doesn't need to be installed on the target machines (equivalent to `dotnet publish`).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `typeof(...)`, you are importing types from the current runtime (.NET Core 2). If you want to make a .NET Framework application from .NET Core, you need to import mscorlib from .NET Framework on Windows, or mono, and use the types from it. See my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73434552/4205390