# How can I run assemblies generated by Mono.Cecil on a Windows Machine?

Tags: c#, windows, mono.cecil

I have been playing around with Mono.Cecil recently, mainly for a compiler that I'm planning on writing. I started by trying out the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39369989/5133585). Here is the code:

```
var myHelloWorldApp = AssemblyDefinition.CreateAssembly(
    new AssemblyNameDefinition("HelloWorld", new Version(1, 0, 0, 0)), "HelloWorld", ModuleKind.Console);

var module = myHelloWorldApp.MainModule;

// create the program type and add it to the module
var programType = new TypeDefinition("HelloWorld", "Program",
    Mono.Cecil.TypeAttributes.Class | Mono.Cecil.TypeAttributes.Public, module.TypeSystem.Object);

module.Types.Add(programType);

// add an empty constructor
var ctor = new MethodDefinition(".ctor", Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Public | Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.HideBySig
    | Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.SpecialName | Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName, module.TypeSystem.Void);

// create the constructor's method body
var il = ctor.Body.GetILProcessor();

il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0));

// call the base constructor
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Call, module.ImportReference(typeof(object).GetConstructor(Array.Empty<Type>()))));

il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Nop));
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Ret));

programType.Methods.Add(ctor);

// define the 'Main' method and add it to 'Program'
var mainMethod = new MethodDefinition("Main",
    Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Public | Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Static, module.TypeSystem.Void);

programType.Methods.Add(mainMethod);

// add the 'args' parameter
var argsParameter = new ParameterDefinition("args",
    Mono.Cecil.ParameterAttributes.None, module.ImportReference(typeof(string[])));

mainMethod.Parameters.Add(argsParameter);

// create the method body
il = mainMethod.Body.GetILProcessor();

il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Nop));
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello World"));

var writeLineMethod = il.Create(OpCodes.Call,
    module.ImportReference(typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { typeof(string) })));

// call the method
il.Append(writeLineMethod);

il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Nop));
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Ret));

// set the entry point and save the module
myHelloWorldApp.EntryPoint = mainMethod;
myHelloWorldApp.Write("HelloWorld.exe");
```

Note that I changed `module.Import` to `module.ImportReference` since the former is apparently obsoleted.

I put this into a .NET 5 project, and this created a `HelloWorld.exe`. Since I was on macOS, I tried running the exe with mono:

```
mono HelloWorld.exe
```

And it printed "Hello World". So far so good.

The problem arises, when I sent this `HelloWorld.exe` to my friend who is on a Windows machine. When he runs it like this (Note that he doesn't have mono on Windows):

```
.\HelloWorld.exe
```

It outputs the error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Console, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependences. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> at `HelloWorld.Program.Main(String[] args)`

I tried to look up the error message, but all the results were about not able to find `System.Runtime`. And is `System.Console` even an assembly? Isn't it a class?

**How can I run the exe on a Windows Machine?** Is there something I need to change in the code? Or is there something that the Windows machine needs to install? I think this might have to do with me using .NET 5, but the Windows machine only has .NET Framework.

---

Question ends there, below are my findings:

As the "control group", I tried doing the simplest Hello World C# program:

```
class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Compiling that with `csc` on macOS (i.e. the Mono compiler), and running the output exe on Windows. This works, so I disassembled (using [`dotnet-ildasm`](https://github.com/pjbgf/dotnet-ildasm)) both the exe produced by Mono.Cecil and the exe produced by `csc`, and compared them. The most interesting difference I found is that there are these extra assembly references in the "broken" exe:

```
.assembly extern System.Private.CoreLib
{
  .publickeytoken = ( 7C EC 85 D7 BE A7 79 8E ) // ....y.
  .ver 5:0:0:0
}


.assembly extern System.Console
{
  .publickeytoken = ( B0 3F 5F 7F 11 D5 0A 3A ) // .._.....
  .ver 5:0:0:0
}
```

Comment: You use Mono Cecil in a .NET 5 application to produce the assembly, so that when functions like `ImportReference` are being called, Mono Cecil uses .NET 5 runtime information to locate the type metadata and assembly references (why `System.Console` and `System.Private.CoreLib` are there). So the final assembly might run on .NET 5, but can fail on other .NET implementations.

Comment: @LexLi but `System.Console` and `Console.WriteLine` isn’t a .NET 5-specific thing, right? It’s part of the .NET _standard_. And why is `System.Private.CoreLib` even there? Did I use anything from that assembly in my hello world program?

Comment: I don't want to go too deep into the details. Since .NET Standard was defined long after .NET platforms (.NET Framework, Xamarin, and Mono) are out there, the workarounds to make the standard feasible (assemblies like `System.Private.CoreLib`) are unavoidable. That makes it difficult to explain further, but you can debug into Mono Cecil to better understand how the actual assembly references are resolved and help yourself.

Comment: @LexLi I see. I've also tried setting my project's `<TargetFramework>` to `netstandard2.0`, and that worked (i.e. created an exe that I can run on a Windows machine with .NET Framework). However, now I can't do `dotnet run` anymore. I had to `dotnet build` and run the built binary with mono, which is rather annoying. I guess now the problem is, how can I make Mono Cecil import things from .NET standard, but also keeping my project's target framework as .NET 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `typeof(...)`, you are importing types from the current runtime (.NET 5). I guess you want to compile for .NET Framework, because that's installed on Windows. You need to import mscorlib from .NET Framework on Windows, or mono (no idea where it is on Mac):

```cs
// Load mscorlib from .NET framework or mono
// C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll (Windows, 64-bit)
// C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll (Windows, 32-bit)
// /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll (Linux)
// /usr/lib/mono/4.8-api/mscorlib.dll (Linux, reference-only)
var mscorlib = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule("/usr/lib/mono/4.8-api/mscorlib.dll");
```

When you call the base constructor, call the constructor of the object in the loaded mscorlib, not the .NET 5 one:

```cs
// module.TypeSystem.Object.Resolve() will resolve to .NET 5
var objectCtor = mscorlib.GetType("System.Object").Methods.Where(m => m.IsConstructor && !m.HasParameters).First();
// call the base constructor
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Call, module.ImportReference(objectCtor)));
```

Again, do not import string from the current runtime:

```cs
// add the 'args' parameter
var argsParameter = new ParameterDefinition("args",
    Mono.Cecil.ParameterAttributes.None, new ArrayType(module.TypeSystem.String));
```

If you look up [System.Console docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=netframework-4.8), you see that it's in mscorlib, so you can get the type reference:

```cs
// Obtain System.Console from .NET Framework
var netfxConsole = mscorlib.GetType("System.Console");
// Obtain the correct WriteLine method, there might be a better way
var writeLine = netfxConsole
                .Methods
                .Where(m => m.Name == "WriteLine" && m.Parameters.Count == 1 && m.Parameters[0].ParameterType == mscorlib.TypeSystem.String)
                .First();

// Use .NET Framework's Console.WriteLine
var writeLineMethod = il.Create(OpCodes.Call, module.ImportReference(writeLine));
```

And this works with mono (Linux) and on Windows (VM)

However, the disassemblers (monodis, ilspycmd) show that there are 2 `mscorlib`s referenced (one from `module.TypeSystem` and one from the loaded `mscorlib`, which seem to be the same):

```
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .ver 4:0:0:0
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 ) // .z\V.4..
}
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .ver 4:0:0:0
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 ) // .z\V.4..
}
.assembly 'HelloWorld'
{
  .hash algorithm 0x00000000
  .ver  1:0:0:0
}
.module HelloWorld // GUID = {CB393199-8BA7-4CB5-8B55-1F81ED0FA68C}
```